# How to use typescript object to render a partial view

Tags: javascript, typescript, knockout.js

As of now I am rendering buttons using an enum and then depending on the type I have different HTML. It goes like so,

```js
export interface control {
  type: controlType;
}

export enum controlType {
  button, 
  switch,
  select
}
```

Then I can call it like so,

```
<!--- ko: if: $data.type === 0 -->
  PUT CODE HERE
<!-- /ko -->
```

I'm trying to help optimization by using an object and then rendering a view of the code in a different file. I can't quite get it to work and any help would be appreciated. So far I have,

```js
export interface control {
  type: {
    button: 'folder/button.html',
    switch: 'folder/switch.html',
    select: 'folder/select.html'
  }
}
```

Then I thought I could just use something like

```
<!-- ko compose: { view: $data.type } --> <!-- /ko -->
```

that doesn't work and I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

`interface` only exists to check your types at build time. Since your `type` object is defined inside the interface,  `button: 'folder/button.html',` and others don't exists in run time *unless* you assign `$data.type` with the exact same object as `type` in your interface.

Instead, you can define `controlType` as a string `enum`:

```
export enum controlType {
  button = 'folder/button.html', 
  switch = 'folder/switch.html',
  select = 'folder/select.html'
}

export interface control {
  type: controlType;
}
```

Now, you can create an object of type `control` like:

```
const $data: control = {
  type: controlType.button
}
```

This forces the `$data.type` have only 3 possible values and allow you to use it like:

```
<!-- ko compose: { view: $data.type } --> <!-- /ko -->
```